# Form of an analytic function

Tags: p-adic-number-theory, formal-power-series

Let $K$ be a field of characteristic zero complete with respect to a non archimedian absolute value with a residue field of characteristic $p>0$.
Let $\mathcal{H}^\dagger=\cup_{\varepsilon >0} \mathcal{A}(]1-\varepsilon, \infty])$. Where $\mathcal{A}(]1-\varepsilon,\infty])$ is the set of analytic function on $]1-\varepsilon,\infty]$.
I would like to prove that if we take $m \in 1+\frac{1}{x}\mathcal{H}^\dagger$ then we can write $m$ in the form
$$\prod\limits_{i\geq 1} (1+\frac{\mu_i}{x^i}).$$

Thanks for the help !

Comment: Any $f(y)\in 1+yK[[y]]$ is of the form $\prod_{i \ge 1} (1+u_i y^i)$, if $f\in p^{-r} O_K[[yp^{-\epsilon}]]$ what is the growth of the $u_i$

Comment: Could you show us what you have tried so far ?

Comment: @reuns I don"t understand your answer, what are $r$ and $\epsilon$ ?

Comment: @Olórin The only thing that I computed is that such a form is equal to $$\frac{\prod \mu_i}{\prod x^i} \prod (1+\mu_i x^i) $$